# How to get Ip address of the request comming in Ruby TCP server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tcp, tcpclient

I have made a coded to receive the TCP request in Ruby, but I am not able to get the Ip addresss of the coming request.
My code is as:

```
 require 'socket'
puts "Starting the Server..................."
server = TCPServer.new 53492 # Server bound to port 53492
loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    # client = server.accept # Wait for a client to connect
    # client.puts "Hello you are there!"
    result = ''
    ansiString = client.recv(100).chomp
    p "String = #{ansiString}"
   begin
  #  How to get the request IP adress here
    rescue Errno::EPIPE
      puts "Connection broke!"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`IPSocket#peeraddr`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.1/libdoc/socket/rdoc/IPSocket.html#method-i-peeraddr).

```
p client.peeraddr(false)[3]
```

Or a bit more legibly:

```
address_family, port, hostname, numeric_address = client.peeraddr(false)
p numeric_address
```

Answer (score 1):

```
require 'socket'
puts "Starting the Server..................."
server = TCPServer.new 53492 # Server bound to port 53492
loop do
  Thread.start(server.accept) do |client|
    # client = server.accept # Wait for a client to connect
    # client.puts "Hello you are there!"
    p "Client address = #{client.peeraddr[3]}"  ## Answer
    result = ''
    ansiString = client.recv(100).chomp
    p "String = #{ansiString}"
   begin
  #  How to get the request IP adress here
    rescue Errno::EPIPE
      puts "Connection broke!"
    end
  end
end
```